# install maven artefact with dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I want to create a maven artifact from an existing jar. So far so good. The problem is that in said jars class-Path several other jars are referenced.

Is there a way to also create artifacts from the jars in the parent jars classpath or include them in the artifact?

Secondly the sources and javadocs are not included in the jar itself. So how do you bundle them with the artifact?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to also create artifacts from the jars in the parent jars classpath or include them in the artifact?

You would probably add the dependent jars as a dependencies to the maven artifact you are packaging. If you are familiar with maven at all, this is how any artifact out there work.

> Secondly the sources and javadocs are not included in the jar itself. So how do you bundle them with the artifact?

There is a [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html) for this.